# wordpress - injecting css and javascript in front-page.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a multipage HTML template that has several javascript files and css files. I am trying to convert this template to Wordpress theme. To start , I added the template's `index.html` to wordpress `front-page.php` and in `functions.php` , I added this

```
<?php

function travel_register_styles(){ 
 // Enqueue CSS files here     
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
  ...
  ...
}
    
function travel_register_scripts() {

    // Enqueue JavaScript files here      
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-3.4.1.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array(), '1.0', false);
   ...
   ...
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'travel_register_styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'travel_register_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'travel_register_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'travel_register_styles');

?>
```

And in `front-page.php` (HTML has head tag, multiple section tags and body tag) , I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   ...
  <?php
      wp_head();
   ?>
   ...
  </head>        
  <body>
    ...

<header class="header-area">
</header>

<section>     
</section>

<section    
</section>
//more sections 
 ...
   <?php
        wp_body_open();
    ?>
    ...
    </body>

</html>
```

But when I visit the site it looks broken. Some css and javascript is applied but in whole page is broken. Under dev tools, I see that all css and Javascript have been loaded.

When I insert javascript and css files directly inside `front-page.php` using  `<script src="` , the page looks fine

I made sure that when I am enqueuing css and javascript files , I do that in same order as when I am inserting them directly using `<script>` tags .

Is there anything else I need to do to make sure that page looks same as when I am inserting CSS and JS directly ?